# Prevent update of SharePoint document library item when clicking [OK] button in Edit Form

Tags: 2007, document-library, event-receivers, event-handlers

I am developing a SharePoint (2007) document library item event receiver to force the user to click on the [`Cancel`] button instead of the [`OK`] button in the Edit Form (`EditForm.aspx`), since clicking on the [`OK`] button is perceived as an update, even if none of the values are modified. In order to achieve this, I am overriding the `itemUpdating` method with the following code:

```
bool propertiesChanged = false;
foreach (SPField field in properties.ListItem.Fields)
{
    if (field.Hidden || field.Sealed || field.ReadOnlyField)
    {
        continue;
    }

    if ((properties.BeforeProperties[field.Title] == null ^ properties.AfterProperties[field.Title] == null)
        || (properties.BeforeProperties[field.Title] != null
            && properties.AfterProperties[field.Title] != null
            && !properties.BeforeProperties[field.Title].ToString().Equals(properties.AfterProperties[field.Title].ToString())))
    {
        propertiesChanged = true;
        break;
    }
}

if (!propertiesChanged)
{
    properties.Cancel = true;
    properties.ErrorMessage = "If you did not intend to modify this item, please click on your browser's [Back] button and press [Cancel] instead of [OK].";
}
```

The document library contains a date field, a couple of check-box fields and a couple of drop-down/choice fields. But this effort is riddled with challenges causing me concern that I may be in the wrong path.

- I wanted to access the column values using the internal name of the field (and not the display name), but I kept getting `null` values when employing the internal name with the code `properties.BeforeProperties[properties.ListItem.Fields[field.Title].InternalName]`
- For a check-box, `properties.BeforeProperties` yielded `0` and `properties.AfterProperties` yielded `false`, thereby causing the code to indicate that a property has changed, when actually it did not (since `0` and `false` are semantically the same)
- In consecutive runs, fields with textual values that already have some values have an empty BEFORE value and actual AFTER value. This behavior is alternative (and very odd!)
- With all the odd behavior I am encountering, `propertiesChanged` is always `true`, so the code never executes the Cancel/ErrorMessage block at the end

I need to understand what I am doing and fix it. MSDN documentation is a bit lacking in this area, with no good examples or best practices/recommendations.